# How do I build the trap for defeating the Kayran?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Can someone please give me a hint where I have to look next?

I have the iron frame and my next goal is to look for the Ostermurk. I know it's location by now. But does this rule out building the trap? I want the achievement for cutting of a tentacle with the trap, so I really need it.

Is there some option later to finish it? I am bit confused.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even know you could use a trap to cut off a tentacle. I just did it the good old manly way, trap one of his tentacles in a ward thingy, then use brute force to slice and dice :p

Comment: @lyrion The manly way is to use ones brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you have to do is to buy the Diagram from Cedric the Elf in the slums for 276 Orens. When you have all the materials to build the trap you have to go to any craftsman in the port and they will build it for you. Once you built it go fight the Kayran then. No you can still build it after that quest. That quest is only there to make the anti-poison for the Kayran's venom. It gives you a massive buff to negate poison damage.